# Why does Mathematica take an aeon to solve an inequality?

Tags: performance-tuning, symbolic, inequalities

I gave Mathematica this inequality to solve:

```
Assuming[{0 < p <= 1/2, m > 0, A > 0, B > 0, C > 0}, 
Reduce[a^(-2 p) e^((4 p)/(1 + 2 p + 2 m)) + 
A a^(2 m + 1) e^((-2 - 4 m)/(1 + 2 m + 2 p)) - 
B a^(1/2 + m - p) e^((-1 - 2 m + 2 p)/(1 + 2 m + 2 p)) <= C, a]]
```

and for some reason, it takes an aeon to solve. I went shopping and it was still running when I returned. Why is it taking so long? I cannot spot why

Note that coding it as

```
Reduce[{a^(-2 p) e^((4 p)/(1 + 2 p + 2 m)) + 
A a^(2 m + 1) e^((-2 - 4 m)/(1 + 2 m + 2 p)) - 
B a^(1/2 + m - p) e^((-1 - 2 m + 2 p)/(1 + 2 m + 2 p)) <= C, 
0 < p <= 1/2, m > 0, e > 0, A > 0, B > 0, C > 0}, a]
```

also does not solve in a finite amount of time

Comment: I don't have an answer, but a few notes: you use the variable `e` in your formula, but as it doesn't appear in your assumptions, so I'm assuming you meant `E` (the universal constant) rather than `e` (which is just another variable). Also, the `C` symbol is reserved by Mathematica; this probably isn't a problem here, but best to wrap it in a `Block` form like this: `Block[{a,p,m,A,B,C}, Assumptions[...]]`. Also, you might want to put something like `Element[{a,p,m,A,B,C}, Reals]` in your assumptions and play around with function chains like `TrigReduce@ExpToTrig@Simplify[ineql]`.

Comment: there simply is no general analytic reduction.  Substitute some specific values for `m,p,A,B,C` so you have an expression in `a` only and you will see `Reduce` still cant do anything with it.